# What is $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$?

Tags: notation, sheaf-theory

I read from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves the following definition:

A ringed topological space consists of a topological space $X$ endowed with a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_X$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a local ring for every $x\in X$. How do we define $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ as I was unable to find it from the book?

Comment: Isn't it just the stalk of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ at $x$?

Comment: Ah. I see. I just thought that as Liu gives the notation for the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ to be $\mathcal{F}_x$, I thought that the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_X$ would be denoted by $\left (\mathcal{O}_X\right )_x$ rather that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to define the **stalk** ${\cal O}_{X,x}$:

- The space of germs lying over $x$. Such germs are equivalence classes of elements of $F(U)$, where $U$ ranges over open sets containing $x$, subject to the relation $a\sim b$ for $a\in F(U)$, $b\in F(V)$ and $a|_W=b|_W$ for some $W\subseteq U,V$ containing $x$.
- The direct limit $\varinjlim F(U)$ taken over open sets $U$ containing $x$.

Comment: Don't you mean direct limit?

Comment: @user115654 Yes. Yes I do.